# Linked list Fibonacci sequence runtime error

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, fibonacci

My program saves the odd and even numbers seperately in linked lists among a given first n numbers of the Fibonacci sequence. Its in C.

When allocating the Head nodes I get a runtime error, Stopped Responding. I'm not able to locate the problem. It may even be about something else I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance

```
struct odd{
       int value;
       struct odd * next;
};

struct even{
       int value;
       struct even * next;
};

struct list{

       struct odd * oHead;
       struct odd * oCurrent;

       struct even * eHead;
       struct even * eCurrent;
};

typedef struct list * List;

void init(int i, List fib){ // allocates the linked list according to first i numbers of the Fibonacci sequence

     int evenCount;
     int oddCount;
     int j;

     /*Calculates the count of even and odd numbers */

     for( j = 0 ; j < evenCount ; j++){
           if(j == 0){
                    **fib->eHead->next = (struct even*)malloc(sizeof(struct even));**
                    fib->eCurrent = fib->eHead->next;
           }
           else{
                fib->eCurrent->next = (struct even*)malloc(sizeof(struct even));
                fib->eCurrent = fib->eCurrent->next;
           }
     }
     for( j = 0 ; j < oddCount ; j++){
           if(j == 0){
                    **fib->oHead->next = (struct odd*)malloc(sizeof(struct odd));**
                    fib->oCurrent = fib->oHead->next;

           }
           else{
               fib->oCurrent->next = (struct odd*)malloc(sizeof(struct odd));
               fib->oCurrent = fib->oCurrent->next;
           }
     }
}

main(){
   List fib
   init(15,fib);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any allocations..

Comment: `fib` is an uninitalised pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Look harder, although as has been pointed out by others, there aren't enough of them.

Comment: It is initialised in main

Comment: @Sangratura no it is not. Local variables are not implicitly initialized to zero.

Comment: @Sangratura "They are set in the part I ommited". Please show the real code. Otherwise you are wasting our time. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kaylum I followed the guide and omitted unnecessary parts.

Comment: @Sangratura Ok, then you misunderstood the guide. Your code needs to be *complete*. By leaving out important initialisation or variable assignments the code is no longer *complete*. Think about it, having those parts omitted can cause problems in the code as shown - so we can't tell whether it is a real bug or because you purposely didn't show it.

Comment: @kaylum How many times the loops run is irrelevant for the problem I can tell that.

Comment: if the counters really were not set then it is Undefined Behaviour resulting in an indeterminate number of loop executions. Which can lead to the exact error you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you've not set `evenCount` and `oddCount` but if they're greater than 0 then this line

```
fib->eHead
```

is dereferencing a pointer that's NULL. The following line is not initialization

```
List fib;
```

That's a declaration of a pointer to a List object that has not been initialized yet. If your typedef was...

```
typedef struct list List;
```

It would initialize an empty struct on the stack but that's not what you're doing. If you do change the type declaration you're still using pointers in this

```
struct list{
       struct odd * oHead;
       struct odd * oCurrent;
       struct even * eHead;
       struct even * eCurrent;
};
```

so the same problem applies, you cannot dereference any of them until they allocated.

With regards `evenCount` and `oddCount` you should explicitly set them in the function or you have undefined behavior.

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.
>
> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, then:
>
> if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer; if it has
> arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero; if
> it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
> according to these rules; if it isaunion, the ﬁrst named member is
> initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

Comment: They are set in the part I ommited and replaced with /*Calculates the count of even and odd numbers */, though I should have been more clear.

Comment: Then the problem is your List is not initialized before it gets used.

Comment: I don't understand your comment `typedef struct list List; `.  That's type definition, not initialization.

Comment: Changing the typedef and the parameters as you suggested didnt solve the problem, isnt it initialized if I just do List list if its not a pointer ?

Comment: The internal objects to List are also pointers that have not been initialized, this line `fib->eHead->next` is dereferencing two pointers `fib` then `fib->eHead`. You need to read up on pointers and the difference between the stack and the heap.

Comment: How am I supposed to do it properly? I cant alloc fib->eHead without getting an error.

Comment: "without getting an error". There certainly was an error wen you accessed `fib->eHead`. It was just not the error you expected. That's because it is Undefined Behaviour to access uninitialised variables. UB means the behaviour cannot be predicted (ie, can't rely on it crashing immediately).

Comment: You need to allocate every pointer using `malloc` before you use it.